# How to immediately stop a lottie animation if button is clicked in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, lottie

I have this click event for my button:

```
        private void BtnRecord_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            if (BtnRecord.BackgroundColor == Color.Coral)
            {
                blue_record_lottie.Loop = true;
                blue_record_lottie.AutoPlay = true;
                blue_record_lottie.Play();
                BtnRecord.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
            }

            else if (BtnRecord.BackgroundColor == Color.Red)
            {
                BtnRecord.BackgroundColor = Color.Coral;
                blue_record_lottie.AbortAnimation(blue_record_lottie.ToString());
                blue_record_lottie.Loop = false;
                blue_record_lottie.AutoPlay = false;
            }
        }
```

It just stops the animation of the button if the button color is red and when the animation is done playing. The animation will have to finish from the start of the animation to the end, and then it stops. I want it to immediately stop when I click the button.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to stop the animation in the midle of the animation, or immediately go back to the very first frame of the animation?

Comment: @Hacki, you can also set LottieAnimationView.Progress=0 to reset this animation, I do one sample that you can take a look:https://github.com/CherryBu/animationsample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make your Animation go back immediately to the very first state of the animation, you can do this:

```
Animation.PlayFrameSegment(0, 0);
```

This will play the very first Frame of your animation, after that, you can restart the animation like you would normally do.

Answer (score 1):

Since Xamarin Lottie 4.0, the PlayFrameSegment method does not exist anymore. Instead you will have to use either:

```cs
Animation.PlayMinAndMaxFrame(0.0f, 0.0f);
```

or

```cs
Animation.PlayMinAndMaxProgress(0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Animation.playAnimation;` to start

`Animation.pauseAnimation;` to stop